# How to tell the type of a PyObject?

Tags: python

I am writing a C function which takes PyObject* as parameter and processes it according to the type of the data. E.g. if it is a string, an integer, a double, a list, etc.

I am looking for ways to check the type of the data, could you show me some examples?

I am using CPython 3.8.

Comment: Can you use `type()` from python?

Answer (score 7):

Most of the built-in types in Python have associated type-check functions, which you can look up in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/concrete.html). For example, `PyLong_Check` checks whether an object is an int (accepting subclasses), and `PyLong_CheckExact` does the same check, but rejecting subclasses:

```
if (PyLong_Check(whatever)) {
    // do int stuff
}
```

---

There are also C-level equivalents of `type` and `isinstance`.

To access an object's type in C, you can use [`Py_TYPE(whatever)`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.Py_TYPE). This gives you a borrowed reference to the object's type - it's equivalent to accessing the object's `ob_type` field. The value is of type `PyTypeObject*`; you can cast it to `PyObject*` if you need to.

Alternatively, if you need a new reference, you can use [`PyObject_Type(whatever)`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Type). This gives you a `PyObject*`; you can cast it to a `PyTypeObject*` if you need to. (The difference in pointer types has nothing to do with the difference in reference count handling.)

---

There are two ways to do `isinstance` at C level, depending on what you actually want. The first is [`PyObject_IsInstance(whatever, WhateverClass)`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsInstance), which is exactly equivalent to `isinstance`, including handling virtual subclasses and false `__class__` attributes the way `isinstance` does, and handling tuples of classes as the second argument. This is often not what you really want at C level, since passing a `PyObject_IsInstance` test guarantees nothing about an object's memory layout.

The second is [`PyObject_TypeCheck(whatever, WhateverClass)`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_TypeCheck), which requires that `whatever` is a "concrete" instance of `WhateverClass` - the actual type of `whatever` has to either be `WhateverClass` or a "real" descendant of `WhateverClass`. This ensures that `whatever` has the actual C-level members an instance of `WhateverClass` is expected to have.

For example, with the following classes:

```
import abc

class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class B: pass

A.register(B)

class C:
    __class__ = int

b = B()
c = C()
```

`PyObject_IsInstance(b, A)` and `PyObject_IsInstance(c, int)` would both be true, but `PyObject_TypeCheck(b, A)` and `PyObject_TypeCheck(c, int)` would be false.

Type-specific type-check macros like `PyLong_Check` behave like `PyObject_TypeCheck`, not `PyObject_IsInstance`. They ignore virtual subclasses and false `__class__` attributes.

Comment: Would `PyObject_IsInstance` end up calling back into python level code if there is a metaclass? If I understand correctly you can implement custom implementations in python for this using metaclasses. And does that differ from `PyObject_TypeCheck`?

Comment: @flakes: `PyObject_IsInstance` will call `__instancecheck__`, which may invoke Python-level code. `PyObject_TypeCheck` will not call Python-level code.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [`PyObject_Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Type)

> `PyObject* PyObject_Type(PyObject *o)`
>
> When *o* is non-`NULL`, returns a type object corresponding to the object
> type of object *o*. On failure, raises SystemError and returns `NULL`.
> This is equivalent to the Python expression `type(o)`. This function
> increments the reference count of the return value. There’s really no
> reason to use this function instead of the common expression
> `o->ob_type`, which returns a pointer of type `PyTypeObject*`, except when
> the incremented reference count is needed.

You might also want to look into [`PyObject_TypeCheck`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_TypeCheck) if you want to handle subclasses correctly.

Comment: Great answer. In what cases do you want to ensure the reference count is increased? Is this to prevent the class itself from being garbage collected?

Comment: @flakes: The exact same cases you'd want to increase the reference count of any other object: when you need a new reference that you own, independent of the original reference. For example, if you want to return a reference from a function you're writing, you usually need to ensure it's a new reference, not a borrowed reference.